# local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

Tags: sql, oracle, select, collections, plsql

I have a question regarding using of collections in Oracle SQL functions.

There are definitions of types in package:

```
/* Types of package*/
create or replace PACKAGE "test" AS 

TYPE type_record_1 IS record ( id_num NUMBER , timestamp_num NUMBER,value NUMBER);
TYPE type_table_1 IS TABLE OF type_record_1; 
TYPE type_record_2 IS record ( id_num NUMBER , timestamp_num NUMBER,pValue NUMBER);
TYPE type_table_2 IS TABLE OF type_record_2; 
END test;
```

Problem is in functions_2.
function_2 uses output from function_1.
The error message occurs when I try select in function_2.
Error message "local collection types not allowed in SQL statements".

Could you please help? What is wrong with using of collections in functions?

```
/*function 1*/
FUNCTION function_1
RETURN  type_table_1
IS
table_1 type_table_1;
BEGIN
-- select values from
SELECT id_num, timestamp_num, value --type_record_1 (id_num, timestamp_num, value) 
BULK COLLECT INTO table_1 
    FROM (
      SELECT       
        l.id_num,
        EXTRACT(hour from end_time) * 60 + EXTRACT(minute from end_time) as timestamp_num,
        l.value
      FROM INTERVAL_F l
      WHERE id_num IN (SELECT id_num FROM table_rev)
    );

 RETURN table_1;

 END function_1;


 /*function 2*/
 FUNCTION function_2
         (
          table_1 IN type_table_1
          )
 RETURN type_table_2
 IS 
 table_2 type_table_2;
 BEGIN

 SELECT type_record_2(id_num , timestamp_num , pValue)
 BULK COLLECT INTO table_2 FROM (
 SELECT  id_num
       , timestamp_num 
       , value as pValue
       FROM table(table_1)  -- ERROR IS HERE
       );

 RETURN table_2;
 END function_2;
```

Comment: Because it's simply not allowed to use `table()` operator on  collections that are declared not at a schema level(prior to 12c). 12c relaxes this restriction and it's enough to declare a collection in a package specification to be able to "query" it (use `table()` operator) elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achive that you should use something like:

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE type_record_1...
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE type_table_1 AS TABLE OF type_record_1;
/

Oracle does not allow types declared in package to be casted as table. 
I talk about Oracle until 11, still not check 12c new features :(.

Comment: Thank you it works! Is there any way to do it around this limitation without creating data types at the schema level?

Comment: Long answer is No, because it is related to scope of data types. I hope this limitation to be escaped in the future versions but until 11g R2 it is pretty normal behavior.